# How to solve importError: no module named 'docX.api'; 'docx' is not a package

Tags: python

I installed `python-docx` package on my Windows 10 machine, but it is not working. I keep on getting the error

> "importError: No module named `docx.api`; `docx` is not a package.

So I tried the standard things I could find on internet:

1. Uninstall `docx` => was not installed
2. Reinstall `lxml`
3. Three different install methods (pip, easy-install and via the distribution itself) => all "successful installed"
4. Update `setupTools`

I'm running python in normal CMD windows 10.
Python version 3.5.1
Other python scripts are working fine.

If I look at the modules installed in Python at this moment (pip list):

```
Package     Version
----------- -------
lxml        4.4.1  
pip         19.2.3 
pypiwin32   223    
python-docx 0.8.10 
pythonnet   2.3.0  
pywin32     223    
setuptools  41.2.0 
XlsxWriter  1.0.5  




CODE:
from docx import Document
from docx.shared import Inches

document = Document()
document.add_heading("Python Word Doc")

document.add_paragraph("This is a test")
document.save('Demo1.docx')
```

The script creates a folder called "**pychache**" containing a file `docx.cpython-35.pyc`
But I was expecting it would create a word file.

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem: I also had a python file called

'docx.py'

After renaming that file it worked perfectly.